# MongoDB retrun array of Items from other arrays, with reduced datapoints

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a user object that looks (roughly) like the example below - a user containg Arrays of Objects for "autos" "boats" and "planes" - each object COULD have an image URL, but many do not, I want an array of ALL the image URLs form a user (regardless of which group they are in) and I want SOME but NOT ALL of the object that is associated with that image.

DATA MODEL

```
{
    user: STRING,
    autos: [
        {
            make: STRING,
            model: STRING,
            year: NUMBER,
            price: NUMBER,
            image: STRING
        }
    ],
    boats: [
        {
            make: STRING,
            model: STRING,
            year: NUMBER,
            price: NUMBER,
            image: STRING
        }
    ],
    planes: [
        {
            make: STRING,
            model: STRING,
            year: NUMBER,
            price: NUMBER,
            image: STRING
        }
    ]
}
```

This is a reduced "object" in each of these arrays, the real data contains many points that are specific to each of these TYPES, and I cannot change the model at this point.

So I am able to pull back an array of Image URLs from the arrays, and concat them into a single array, But then I just have URLS... what I want is the "make" and "model" and "image URL" for each

Here is the Query I've got

```
query = [
    {
        $match: matchCriteria
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            image: {
                $filter: {
                    input: {
                        $concatArrays: [
                            '$autos.image',
                            '$boats.image',
                            '$planes.image'
                        ]
                    },
                    cond: {
                        $and: [ // skip records without image data
                            { $eq: [{ $type: "$$this" }, "string"] },
                            { $ne: ["$$this", ""] }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
];
```

this gives me data looking like this

```
"data": [
    "https://www.yourPics.com/see?image=image4",
    "https://www.yourPics.com/see?image=image5",
    "https://www.yourPics.com/see?image=image6",
    "https://www.yourPics.com/see?image=image1",
    "https://www.yourPics.com/see?image=image2",
    "https://www.yourPics.com/see?image=image3",
    "https://www.yourPics.com/see?image=image7",
    "https://www.yourPics.com/see?image=image8",
    "https://www.yourPics.com/see?image=image9",
    "https://www.yourPics.com/see?image=image10",
    "https://www.yourPics.com/see?image=image11"
],
```

But I WANT something that looks like this

```
"data": [
    {
        make:"some make4",
        model:"some model4",
        image: "https://www.yourPics.com/see?image=image4"
    },
    {
        make:"some make5",
        model:"some model5",
        image: "https://www.yourPics.com/see?image=image5"
    },
    {
        make:"some make6",
        model:"some model6",
        image: "https://www.yourPics.com/see?image=image6"
    },
    ...
],
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you also trying to group the result by autos, planes and boats? Or are you simply trying to dump them into one object array?

Comment: Just a single object array - it is the end point for an "image rotator"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're concating just the image attribute of those objects. Doing that, you will certainly end up with just an array of images. Why not concat the entire arrays? As in:

```
$concatArrays: ["$autos", "$boats"]
```

So I have put this [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qFIwLhuXR84) together for you. Using this project:

```
  {
    $project: {
      items: {
        $filter: {
          input: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$autos",
              "$boats"
            ]
          },
          as: "items",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {
                $ne: [
                  "$$items.image",
                  undefined
                ]
              },
              {
                $ne: [
                  "$$items.image",
                  ""
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

You will get this result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "items": [
      {
        "image": "https://pont.com",
        "make": "Pontiac",
        "model": "Sunfire",
        "year": "2004"
      },
      {
        "image": "https://aluma.com",
        "make": "Aluma",
        "model": "X4",
        "price": "100,000",
        "year": "2021"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

From here, excluding the keys you don't want (e.g `year`, `price`) is a trivial matter. Just project only what you want:

```
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      "items.make": 1,
      "items.model": 1,
      "items.image": 1
    }
  }
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/qFIwLhuXR84

Comment: Yes that is very close, and I guess If I hadn't been overthinking it - I would have not added the "image" to the array concat. thanks for that. Hopefully someone will chime in on how to reduce the objects in the array to project just what I need (the real model is quite a bit more bulky than the 5 data points I included)

Comment: @j-p It's trivial to remove those unwanted props. Check out the updated answer.